# How to execute code before the splash screen is displayed?

Tags: wpf, splash-screen

In my app project I use this to display my splash screen image:

```
<SplashScreen Include="Images\SplashScreen.png" />
```

I also use a `Mutex` to prevent the application being opened more than once. However, even with the `Mutex` check in the `App` class constructor the splash screen is displayed before the `Mutex` check is performed.

Is there some way I can perform the check before the splash screen is displayed to prevent the user seeing it on the second instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and show the splash screen programatically, which allows you to control when it is shown and what happens before and after. Add your image with `BuildAction` set to `Resource`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      // ...execute pre action here.
   
      SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen(@"Images\SplashScreen.png");
      splashScreen.Show(true);

      base.OnStartup(e);
      // ...other code and post action.
   }
}
```

See the [`SplashScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) type for more info and please be aware that there two overloads for the [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method. The parameter determines, whether the spalsh screen is automatically closed after the application was loaded. You could pass `false` and use the [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method to determine yourself when it is closed and execute your action afterwards.